# POST method returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, redux

No other post on Stackoverflow was able to provide a fix for my question, so here we go.

I have a React/redux app. I am making a fetch request via an action:

```
export const postNewBase = () => title => {
  fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/addbase`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: title
    })
  })
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Request failed", error);
    });
  };
```

The component calls it:

```
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const title = this.textInput.value.trim();
    this.props.dispatch(postNewBase(title));
}
```

In its basic form my node API looks like this:

```
app.post("/addbase", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send(req.body);
});
```

`Req.body` returns undefined, and `req` does not contain anything matching the `title` provided by the functions. 
What is wrong with my markup?

Comment: Is `API_BASE_URL` another origin? If yes, does your API have CORS enabled?

Comment: @Tholle `API_BASE_URL` is localhost, and CORS is enabled and sent on the backend via headers

Comment: Are you using a body parser? (e.g. [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)?)

Comment: @apokryfos `const bodyParser = require("body-parser")` is in the server.js and `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: What do you see in the browser "Network" developer tab? Specifically what do the response headers and response body look like?

Comment: @Pointy The console log on the client side component returns the title fine. The console log in the dispatched action says `dispatch() {
          return _dispatch.apply(undefined, arguments);
        }`. And the req.body on the server-side log says `{}`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're not allowing JSON encoded bodies for your node application.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

// Server app.
const app = express();

// To support JSON-encoded bodies.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: see comment above